# How to decide between individual versus group level random effect

Tags: regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, group-differences

I have N participants each has inconsistent number of repeated measurements of an outcome Y. Each participant belongs to one of two groups.

My hypothesis is that the levels of Y differ significantly among groups and that the Y rate of change also varies significantly over time.
Should the group be set as fixed or random effect?

Comment: Let me also mention that the individuals have been randomly sampled and the groups were created later using clustering (i.e the original sampling was not done based on the groups).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only have 2 groups and you are interested in the "effect" of the group, then it should be a fixed effect. In R it would look something like:

```
Y ~ time + group + (1|subject)
```

You might also want to fit an interaction between `time` and `group` and possibly allow the fixed effects to vary by subject, with random slopes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. Now because I'm measuring change since baseline(Y=Yi-Y0) does it make sense not to include the main effect of group(at time 0 the response is 0 for everyone) and only have time as main effect and time*group interaction?

Comment: Everyone has the same baseline ?

Comment: Wait! Did you subtract everyone's baseline measurement from all their measurements to get zero baseline for everyone?? You definitely shouldn't do that!

Comment: Yes, I aligned the Time for all individuals so the first measurement (whenever this was) is considered as their baseline measurement. Time is expressed as the months after the baseline measurement. Indeed, for every participant I subtracted the later measurements from the very first measurement.

Comment: Aligning time is ok, but manipulating their measurements so that they all have zero baseline is almost always a mistake.

Comment: My logic is that I don't care about their actual value of the response variable but for the difference in the rate of change among groups. I thought that subtracting from the baseline would be equivalent to using the actual response values while adjusting for the baseline measurement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111024/discussion-between-d-c-and-robert-long).